# All possible permutations of parameters using Spock's Unroll

Tags: groovy, integration-testing, spock, end-to-end

I have the following parameters for the same test:

```
  a  |  b  |  c
  1  |  2  |  3
 11  | 22  | 33
```

Spock provides the `@Unroll` annotation for tests similar to this (with this set of parameters you can run to same tests with the vectors [1, 2, 3] and  [11, 22, 33]).

However, I need to run the same test for all the possible permutations (e.g [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 33], [11, 2, 33] and etc, all the 8 combinations). How can I achieve it?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need

```
where:
[a, b, c] << [[1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 13]].combinations()
```

Comment: Super! I have never seen this feature.

Comment: This looks really great!  FWIW however:  I don't think this would work well when the test expectation is particular to the individual permutations - those expectations need to be associated individually with each permutation... which I think would unfortunately defeat the whole intent of this sort of syntax.  Note that the table in the Question here does not include an expectation column (with non-uniform booleans across all rows ;). But this Answer is still great for tests where the expectation is indeed all the same!

Answer (score 0):

To answer cellepo 's comment:
It is possible to have the expectation associated with a permutation by extracting the `c` data pipe.

```
  def "data driven cross-product"() {
    expect:
    Math.max(a, b) == c

    where:
    [a, b] << [[1, 11], [2, 12]].combinations()
    c << [2, 11, 12, 12]
  }
```

`combinations` always returns the permutations in the same order:

```
[['a', 'b'],[1, 2, 3]].combinations() == [['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['a', 3], ['b', 3]]
```

It will be hard to write if it's a combination of many variables though.